# Not able to set the background to a ListView

Tags: image, listview, android-layout, background

I am trying to set background for my List view . I have taken a image from the drawable and set it as background to the layout file then it is giving the result as following screen shot[image: screen with background]

and when i just remove the background am getting the thing which i required but no background.
and screen shot is [image: screen without background]
Is there is any other Syntax to set background for ListView.

And my Code for layout is

```
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"

      >


    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
      </LinearLayout>




And my java code and that is 

String[] names = new String[] { "India", "Malaysia" };
        // Use your own layout and point the adapter to the UI elements which
        // contains the label
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.screen3,
                R.id.label, names));
    }

    @Override

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // Get the item that was clicked
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String keyword = o.toString();
        if(keyword.equals("India"))
        {

            Intent ima1=new Intent(screen3.this,new21.class);

            startActivity(ima1);

        }
        else
        {
            Intent ima2=new Intent(screen3.this,new22.class);
            startActivity(ima2);
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "You selected: " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }
```

And lastly i need is I want the background image with proper listview showing one listitem after another. Thanks in advance
    }

Comment: where are you setting the background?

Comment: @radha Whether Background should be same for all ListView?

Comment: i have done that in xml file as android:background="@drawable/screen6"

Comment: @Venky yes the background for all listview should be same

Comment: @radha Can you come to Causal Chat Room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, Instead of extending ListActivity you can  set layout that contains List View and separate layout for contents of List View.

Java Code :

```
public class Table_Layout extends Activity {

  ListView list_view;
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.table_layout);
      list_view=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
      String[] names = new String[] { "India", "Malaysia" };
      list_view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.screen3,R.id.label, names));
    }
}
```

Main XML that contains List View :table_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/uploading">
    
    <ListView   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/list_view"  
    />
```

Then Contents of List View :screen3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Set you Background for the table_layout.xml so that it will applied for entire List View as you expected.

Comment: Thanks venky. I got the required screen but there is some changes to be done for the layout . i can tell you in chat room

Answer (score 0):

All looks well with your xml file. Try implementing the below mentioned:-

Make an image of the size you want your listview's each row of. And set it as the parent LinearLayout's background. Set:- android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content".

**Hope this helps !! :)**